# How to include a whitespace and non whitespace at the same time in NSRegularExpression?

Tags: iphone, regex, pattern-matching

I want a regex which accepts only these two templates: `a0a 0a0` and `a0a0a0`.
I have been trying the below format but it's not giving the desired result.
I need a single regex which is applicable for both the templates.

```
+ (BOOL)hasPostalCodeValidation:(NSString *)postalCode {
    return [self hasPostalRegex:postalCode 
                    withPattern:@"^[a-z]+[0-9]+[a-z]+(\\ |\\S[^a-z0-9])?[0-9]+[a-z]+[0-9]"
             withTemplateString:@"A0A 0A0"];
}
```

If any one knows what should be the regex for these two templates please do give the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply make the space optional? Also, you should remove the `+` quantifiers since they mean "one or more", and you seem to want "exactly one".

Also, you might need to include uppercase letters. Usually, regexes are case-sensitive.

```
withPattern:@"^[a-zA-Z][0-9][a-zA-Z]\\s?[0-9][a-zA-Z][0-9]"
```